# Prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{3n} \dfrac{x^{4n}}{(5n)!}$ converges absolutely

Tags: convergence-divergence, factorial

I shall provide the whole problem. To prove is the absolute convergence of

$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{3n}  \dfrac{x^{4n}}{(5n)!}$

I decide to solve this problem using the Quotient Criteria and eventually end up with

$ \dfrac{\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1} x^{4(n+1)}}{(5(n+1))!}}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n}   x^{4n}}{(5n)!}}  = \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1} x^{4(n+1)} (5n)!}{(5(n+1))! (-1)^{n} x^{4n}} = - \dfrac{x^4 (5n)!}{(5(n+1))!}$

Now I just need to prove that $-\dfrac{x^4 (5n)!}{(5(n+1))!}$ converges, which is where I get stuck. It's obvious to me that it converges to $0$ since the bottom part of the equasion grows much faster than the top part.

How do I work with the $(5(n+1))?$

Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Isn't $(-1)^{3n}$ simply $(-1)^n$ though? Anyway, $
(5(n + 1))! = (5n + 5)! = (5n + 5)(5n + 4)(5n + 3)(5n + 2)(5n + 1)(5n)!$, and you missed a minus sign when simplifying the fraction.

Comment: Hint $5(n+1) = (5n+5)$.

Comment: $\sum_{\color{red}{i}=0}^\infty$ has to be fixed everywhere.

Comment: So I can then just simplify the (5n)! and then I still have something like x^4 / (120 + 1370 n + 5625 n^2 + 10625 n^3 + 9375 n^4 + 3125 n^5)

Can I then not just claim geometric series, and the deed is done?

Comment: $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{x^4 }}{{(5n + 5) \cdots (5n + 1)}} = 0
$$ for any fixed $x$, so by the ratio test, the series is absolutely convergent for any $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also great eye by noticing the missing -1! I overlooked that completely

Answer (score 2):

$-\dfrac{x^4 (5n)!}{(5(n+1))!}$ = $-\dfrac{x^4 (5n)!}{(5n+5)!}$  = $-\dfrac{x^4 (5n)!}{(5n+5)...(5n+1)(5n)!} $ = $-\dfrac{x^4}{(5n+5)...(5n+1)}$

$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \dfrac{x^4}{(5n+5)...(5n+1)} = 0$

Comment: In the last line, it's $\lim_{n \to +\infty}$

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for noticing.